# code to remove plugin comments from WP header

Tags: php, wordpress

i am vary new to wordpress and have one website in wordpress , every thing is working fine.

i have also added few security option as mentions in many blogs in internet to secure my blog.
like i have change my wp-include folder name to other name and if someone view source of page, it will be hard for him to know that its wordpress blog.

the problem i have with one plugin, that plugin leave comment in website like

```
<!-- This site is using plugin for wordpress -->
```

i have found this comment in plugin file and remove manually but when ever i update that plugin this comment again appear in source.

i am thinking of proper solution to remove this comment from some code in function.php or custom.php so that i don't need to update that file manually every time i update plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. If you want to write code to remove this, put it in a separate plugin, then when your plugin updates, the modifying plugin won't. Or easier still, just stop updating the original plugin.